# What are the advantages to the OpenID OAuth Extension over OAuth?

Tags: authentication, openid, oauth

Why use the proposed [OpenID OAuth Extension](http://step2.googlecode.com/svn/spec/openid_oauth_extension/latest/openid_oauth_extension.html) over another OAuth-based protocol?

Discovery doesn't seem to be a feature. Although the consumer only needs a claimed identifier to start the authentication process, any authorization will still require that the consumer knows the access token URL, signature methods, and have a shared key/secret with the provider.

One benefit is that there's a specified way to ask for specific authorizations, the openid.oauth.scope argument to the authentication request. And one specific benefit for this is that authentication only - for the benefit of the consumer only, with no verifiable token - is defined for free and can be performed without worrying about keeping track of outstanding tokens or the resources they might require.

Are there examples of alternative ways in use to specify the scopes to be requested, perhaps with something in OpenID discovery? Or could this be handled effectively with some kind of REST navigation before the OAuth process, where one of several request token URLs specific to the desired scopes is discovered by interpreting hypertext starting from a well-known URL?

I am researching a delegated authentication and authorization system with several authorization scopes, where the scopes are relevant for different interactions.  In other words, the consumer needs to tell the provider which scopes should be presented to the user for authorization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OpenID+OAuth extension really has only one significant advantage over standard OAuth:

If you need to authenticate the user *and* access the user's private data, *and* the OpenID Provider happens to also be the OAuth Service Provider (the user authenticates with the same service that holds his private data), then the extension will help the user have just one redirect to the OP+SP instead of two separate ones.  For the user, this is a huge usability win -- if he happens to be authenticating with his SP.

The risks of supporting the extension is adequately supporting users whose OP and SP are not the same entity (you don't want to say you'll support the extension and then inadvertently lock out users whose OP is not also their SP).

Keep in mind what you *really* need to know.  If you only want to access the user's private data, but don't really care who the user is that you're interacting with, use just OAuth.  No reason for the user to give up his identity via OpenID if you're only downloading his photos to offer a photo printing service, for example, or if you already have a non-OpenID account for this user.